# can we categorize twitter streaming tweets?

Tags: php, twitter

If I am not wrong there streaming APIS give current tweet feeds on twitter. 
Can we catogorize these tweets based category like sports, business, news, entertainments? 
Any api call for this?

or do we need algo for this?

I appreciate any helpful reply for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to filter the streams - [take a look at the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter).

Although you cannot create a request to get all, say, football tweets, you can [craft a tracking request](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track) which will find all tweets with the words "football, manu, goal" etc.

Comment: thanks, interesting but less chance to help me! if I want tweets belongs to `politics` category then this can not give me such tweets. consdier this tweets for eg 'Obama recently announced to make xyz changes in parliament'. This tweet does not contain word politics even it belongs to category politics

Comment: Twitter doesn't provide this. You'll have to do it yourself. Sorry!

Comment: thanks dude, I think it seems natural lang processing stuff : ) if you have any idea